# Help with Edith Piaf interview

Tags: oral

I've listened to a few bits in this video 10 times, but I just can't hear them properly. Help please.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8QV_hhVWjs

45 seconds: "Je pense que la vie 't' est amour" - she seems to mistakenly add a t sound here, right?

1m01: I hear something like "g n'oubliez toi" - is it just n'oubliez pas with a weird sound at the beginning, or ... ?

1m29: Is it "Et enfin je l'ai démontré. Le monde est plus critique et j'ai toujours aimé l'espoir" ?  or maybe "mes espoirs"?

1m43: "que vous avez soutenu vos conseils" ? that doesn't even seem grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I hear is:

> - Je pense que la vie c'est l'amour.
> - Il est bien obligatoire [...]
> - Même aux moments les plus critiques, j'ai toujours eu de l'espoir.
> - [...] ces chanteurs que vous avez soutenus de vos conseils.

I agree with jlliagre on most of them except the 3<sup>rd</sup> one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I heard:

> - Je pense que la vie c'est l'amour (ou peut-être : la vie fait l'amour ?)
> - il est bien obligatoire
> - <s>j'ai toujours aimé l'espoir</s>
> - que vous avez soutenus **de** vos conseils

but I misheard the third one... Driblou got it right.